# javascript rich text editor with full recording

Tags: javascript, html, rich-text-editor

I'd like to create rich text editor with ability to capture all possible events regarding document modification and later replay sequence of captured events to reconstruct the same document.

Basically I want to record every change made to the document and having all the deltas recorded I want to be able to "replay" the changes to get the same document.

I have tried YUI editor, tinyMCE but I am missing ability to actually reconstruct the same document. Is there any existing solution with such a functionality ?

Comment: Are you trying to create rich text editor like you said or to use some existing solution?

Comment: I'd prefer to re-use as much as possible existing solution

Answer (score -1):

Try ckeditor.com they API and functionality are the best between all Rich Editor
Look like they site was down a couple hours ago.Follow the link http://www.webspellchecker.net/v3/samples/scayt_ckeditor_plugin.html to try it

Comment: found github repository https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev will try that, thanks